# Rails Install Fails With Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, ruby-2.1

I've just installed Ruby 2.1 using the instructions here for OSX:

https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/Ruby

Everything appears to be working fine and I've installed a few gems without issue.

However, when installing rails using:

```
$ sudo gem install rails -V
```

the installation fails part-way through with the error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
>       no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/atomic-1.1.4-java.gemspec.rz)

I can grab a file from this [URL](https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/atomic-1.1.4-java.gemspec.rz) using curl or by pasting it into the address bar, so it seems the file does exist.

**Why is the installation failing?**

I'm not behind a proxy and using the `--no-http-proxy` flag makes no difference.

Before the error, approximately 100 other files are downloaded successfully:

```
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.0.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.0.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/railties-4.0.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/railties-4.0.2.gemspec.rz
```

... etc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at some point. Have you already tried

```
gem update --system
```